# When is a dependent assembly actually loaded

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following in, say, "Test.dll"

```
if (process)
{
    Whatever whatever = GetWhatever();
}
```

If "Whatever" is defined in another assembly (*not* "Test.dll"), will that assembly only be loaded when "process" is true (assuming "Whatever" is never used elsewhere). More to the point, if the assembly where "Whatever" is defined is only physically present on the host machine when "process" is true, will a runtime error occur when "process" is false. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be loaded "just in time" by the just-in-time compiler.  Which need to know the type when it compiles this code, **before** it starts running.  So the test on *process* is not good enough to prevent an exception.  At a minimum the code inside the if() statement body needs to be moved into another method.  And that method needs to have the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Noinling)] attribute to prevent it from getting jitted too early in the Release build.  And you'll have to give up on ahead-of-time compilers like Ngen.exe and .NET Native.  A plugin framework would be wise.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks very much. Any recommendations then. The issue is that "Test.dll" is actually a VS addin and "Whatever" is a type only available in VS2017 (in a native VS2017 ".dll"). "Test.dll" is compiled under VS2013, will reference the VS2017 assembly containing "Whatever" (both VS2013 and VS2017 are on my development machine), but at runtime itself, "Test.dll" may be running under *any* version of VS. If it's not VS2017 however, then "Whatever" won't be found (since VS2017 won't be on the host machine). The "process" flag above is only true if "Test.dll" is running under VS2017.

Comment: @Hans: Just to clarify your answer (assuming you have no other recommendation), can I assume it's safe to simply move the code to another method and apply the attributes you mentioned. The method will presumably only be JIT-compiled when "process" is true (so the VS2017 "dll" I mentioned will only be loaded at that time). Is that right? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It loads it when the method is called (the one containing the example code). The CLR needs to figure out what that method will do and part of that process is loading assemblies and initializing the types.

Hence, the CLR will throw before `process` is checked.